# Can I call an entry in a resource file using a method or variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have several resource files built for a multilingual MVC 5 site I am working on.

I am using a CMS and the user can select the button text on certain content segments, like "Download" or "View More".

Rendering a value from my resource file using `@Resources.Resource.ViewMore` in my view works fine, but since the content is dynamic depending on what button text the user selects in the CMS, I need to use something like `@Resources.Resource.@Model.getButtonText()` but obviously that will not work.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ResourceManager` class for this

```
@{    
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.Resource));
    @rm.GetString(Model.getButtonText());
}
```

Comment: ResourceManager must be used differently.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk(v=vs.110).aspx

`string value = rm.GetString("NAME_OF_RESOURCE");`

Comment: @ThomasRoskop from his example I think he means Model.getButtonText() is the resource key

Comment: 2 I know. But the most important thing is that GetString() returns a string. So `rm.GetString(Model.getButtonText());` does nothing.
You need to get the result and pass it to the button or so...